# How to manipulate list element on Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to allow the editing of an ordered list using contenteditable.
When the user changes or adds in a new element in the list I want to be able to manipulate the text (e.g. wrap in span tag, replace text etc).

I've created a listener for the Enter key and can get the last list element value.
I've tried to change this and replace with the new value. However this populates the new list element created on the enter press.

```
<div>
   <ol contenteditable=true class="editor">
    <li><br></li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

```
$('.editor' ).on('keydown .editable', function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {   

    var insertText = "<span>"+e.target.lastElementChild.innerText+"</span>";
    e.target.lastElementChild.innerHTML = insertText;
    return true
  }
 });
```

What is the best way to implement this functionality for new entries anywhere in the list not just the end? Open to Jquery solutions

example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qocypL63/4/)

Comment: Might be easier to make the last li editable, and put the event logic on it.  On enter, insert a new li before it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when a child is added to your list, and then update the `previousSibling` to wrap it in a `<span>`:

```js
function subscriber(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
      const prev = node.previousSibling;
      if (prev) {
        prev.innerHTML = `<span>${prev.innerHTML.replace(/<br>$/, '')}</span>`;
      }
    });
  });
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(subscriber);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('ol[contenteditable]'), { childList: true });
```

```css
.editor span::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ol contenteditable class="editor">
  <li>First li</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. Let me explore this further as it seems to do what I want.

Comment: I want to allow nested lists using the TAB key so I've implemented the listeners for TAB.
see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oeLpmx6u/4/

This stops the observer being called.
Is there a way it can be called/triggered manually?

Comment: Resolved it now. Just needed to add subtree:true. { childList: true, subtree: true }. Solution works well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your logic to the last `li`, and perform your logic from the events it emits.

```js
$('.editor .last-item')
  .on('click', function(e){
    // clear out the html so the user can just type
    e.target.innerHTML = '';
  })
  .on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // ignore the enter key so it doesn't insert a new like
      e.preventDefault();
      // create the new li before the last one
      $('<li>'+ e.target.innerHTML.trim() +'</li>').insertBefore(e.target);
      // clear out the html so the user can keep entering items
      e.target.innerHTML = '';
    }
  })
  .on('blur', function(e){
    // if the user leaves the field, change it back to the instructional text
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Click to enter New List Item';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <ol class="editor">
    <li class="last-item" contenteditable=true>Click to enter New List Item</li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I want to allow the user to edit previous elements and this solution restricts that.

Comment: @Schaffer fairly easy to include the contenteditabel on the dynamically created li elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and although it allows editing of the content it stops the creation of a new element when enter is press on anything but the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking action when an edit happens, you could set an interval that will modify the html of the `li` elements as desired.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.editor' ).find('li').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().indexOf('span')==-1){
            $(this).html('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    }
  });
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you might wanna check this let me give you a heads up. instead of using the

```
lastchild.innerHTML
```

replace it with

```
nextSibling.innerHTML
```

like this

```js
$('.editor' ).on('keydown .editable', function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
   
      
   var insertText = "<span>"+e.target.lastElementChild.innerText+"</span>";
   e.target.nextSibling.innerHTML = insertText;
   
   
   return true
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ol contenteditable=true class="editor">
 <li><br></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

```js
$('.editor' ).on('keydown .editable', function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {   

    var insertText = "<span>"+e.target.lastElementChild.innerText+"</span>";
      e.target.nextSibling.innerHTML = insertText;
      return true
     }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does not change the element.